# SFTP file transfer

Tags: ssh, port, sftp, windows-server-2016

When I am trying to send files through SFTP it is not getting sent, but the files can be sent after a server restart. We've checked the firewall and antivirus. Both had no issues found. I'd be thankful if anyone lets us know why after restarting the server the files can be sent for some time and it needs to restart again after some time to send files again.

This is a Windows Server 2016 VM machine. We are getting a `network error: software caused connection abort` error message when using WinSCP to send the files.

Comment: How are you trying to send the files? What commands or programs are you running? What happens when you try to send a file? Do you get any error messages? What do the messages say?

Comment: we are WinSCP to send the files, and error " network error: software caused connection abort".